# Which graphics cards does MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014) have?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, gpu

From "About This Mac" I see that model is "MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014)".

From my understanding, [technical specifications page for MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014)](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP704) lists two graphics cards for that model:
**Graphics and Video support**

- Intel Iris Pro Graphics
- NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M with 2 GB of GDDR5 memory and automatic graphics switching

I can't find any evidence of GPU "NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M" in the system.

1. About This Mac shows only "Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB"
2. System Preferences -> Energy Saver doesn't have "Automatic graphics switching" option (according to https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202043: "If you don't see the automatic graphics switching option, your computer has one graphics system. To confirm, choose Apple menu > About this Mac, press the System Report button, and select Graphics/Displays on the left. The graphics system or systems are listed under Video Card.")
3. About This Mac -> System Report button -> Graphics/Displays on the left. Again, I see only "Intel Iris Pro Graphics"

It rather looks as my Mac has only one graphics system.

- Am I right that my Mac has only Intel Iris Pro graphics system?
- If there is only "Intel Iris Pro" in my Mac how is that possible that official technical specifications page: [MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014) - Technical Specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP704), also lists "NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M"?

Comment: I believe that all configurations of that model came with dedicated graphics. Have you checked to see if your graphics card has failed?

Comment: Listing two cards does not imply that all models had them both.

Comment: The second link is dead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple sold many different versions of the 2014 MBP - different SSD sizes, different RAM amounts, different processors, and on the most expensive machines, a dedicated graphics card.

You may have a machine with only integrated (Intel Iris Pro) graphics. To learn whether or not you are right about only having integrated graphic, you need to know the exact MBP model you have.

One easy way to determine which model yours is:

1. Go to the Apple (top left of screen) and choose "About this Mac".
2. Look at the pop up window and find the serial number listed at the bottom. Copy it.
3. Go to [www.everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/](http://www.everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/) and paste your serial number where it says Enter Identifier.
4. This will bring you to a page with the model of your machine. There you can see all of the specs. If the name has a (DG) after it, then you have a model with dedicated graphics. If it has an (IG) after it, you don't. This is an example with dedicated graphics:

   [image: example]

Comment: (DG) means **dual** graphics, not *dedicated*. To quote Everymac: "\*This model has dual graphics processors -- an AMD Radeon R9 M370X with 2 GB of dedicated GDDR5 SDRAM and an Intel Iris Pro 5200 with 128 MB of "Crystalwell" embedded DRAM (and shared system memory). The system automatically switches between graphics systems based on use (when applications use OpenGL, Core Graphics or other graphically demanding technologies, the system will use the dedicated AMD graphics, otherwise it will use the integrated Intel graphics to conserve battery life)." Well, maybe the terms are interchangeable

Answer (score 0):

You can easily determine whether you have dual graphics processors by opening **Activity Monitor**, and looking at the **Energy** tab.

If you see the column **Requires High Perf GPU**, then you have dual GPU, otherwise you you only have one GPU:

[image: Activity monitor showing that the MacBook Pro has Dual graphics cards]

See [Find out which graphics processor is in use on your MacBook Pro](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202053) for more information.